# Zend_Router, routing to indexController / forward when parameter provided

Tags: php, zend-framework

is there any way to tell the Zend Framework Router:

- " if www.domain.com/test " is called
  forward to indexController -
  forwardAction and recieve the parameter.
- " if www.domain.com" is
  called show indexController /
  indexAction

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this function up into your bootstrap file or wherever you store your rutes:

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
  $this->bootstrap('frontController');
  $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
  $router = $front->getRouter();

  $router->addRoute('testToForward',
                      new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                          ':parameter',
                          array(
                              'controller' => 'index',
                              'action'     => 'forward',
}
```

**Edit**: This way the passed parameter will be passed as 'parameter' to the forward controller.
The second route is provided by default.

Comment: sorry my failure: i mean everytime when an parameter ist provided (like test or hello) route to index/forward.